# Send a message from controller to view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am trying to send an error message from my controller to my view. I tried to use http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/ but my **flash message is not arriving**. Am I redirecting incorrectly?

CrudController.php

```
// execution does reach here.
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data saved!");
$this->redirect(array('crud/admin', 'id' => $currentUser->id));
```

Admin.php aka my view

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')):?>
    <div class="info">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So how do I send a message to my view? I just want to show the message to the user, I honestly don't care how except that the conditional check happens in the controller not view.

---

After `var_dump(Yii::app()->user)`

> object(CWebUser)#21 (14) { ["allowAutoLogin"]=> bool(true)
>   ["guestName"]=> string(5) "Guest" ["loginUrl"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(11) "/site/login" } ["identityCookie"]=> NULL ["authTimeout"]=>
>   NULL ["autoRenewCookie"]=> bool(false) ["autoUpdateFlash"]=>
>   bool(true) ["loginRequiredAjaxResponse"]=> NULL
>   ["_keyPrefix":"CWebUser":private]=> string(32)
>   "a68200d8b7c100a1634ae9aa04a6e79e" ["_access":"CWebUser":private]=>
>   array(0) { } ["behaviors"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["_initialized":"CApplicationComponent":private]=> bool(true)
>   ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL
>   }

Comment: It's likely that the message isn't being set. Do a `var_dump` on your Yii::app()->user, see what's in there flash-message wise.

Comment: @crowhill I added the `var_dump` to my post, I have no clue what it the info means though. Could you take a look?

Comment: after Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data saved!"); Add rows: var_dump(Yii::app()->session->toArray()); die(); Check exist your message in session or no.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar nothing shows up because it is in a controller.

Comment: @J_Strauton it is impossible. My test controller and test action: Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data saved!");  var_dump(Yii::app()->session->toArray());  die(); } Result: Array([long_key] => Data saved! [long_key2] => Array
        (
            [success] => 0
        )

)

Comment: I just pasted that just as you posted and still nothing.

Comment: @J_Strauton could you paste my code to controller(in test action) and print your controller? It is curiously. Call action from url.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but in my case I use TbAlert (YiiBooster). The problem is my PHP version is below 5.4
Would you like to check your PHP Version?